# Apt Stuck On Setting Up libc6

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glibc

I have picked up bad habits from using other Debian distros. So I thought I'll  install Debian WSL2 in my new computer.

Someone told me Debian Stable is too old, so they use Debian testing for newer software. And Ubuntu is based on Debian Sid, so I can just use the Sid version of Debian?

So I chose Debian sid for my WSL source. (When the problem below happened, I looked up the neofetch package. Neofetch still shows it's source is from Debian 11). It worked great the first time/once, but yesterday, when I tried to upgrade WSL just like before, it took a long time and didn't finish. I saw apt frozen on setting up libc6(2.37-13), I don't know what apt was doing.

I tried the easiest solution: Reboot WSL. That didn't  work, so I studied logs for dpkg, and I saw this:

> 2024-01-07 22:15:52 status half-configured libc6:amd64 2.37-13

And I tried to use the solution at [Fix half-installed package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490671/fix-half-installed-package).  The answer recommended:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename`

It doesn't work for me. Apt output these:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-bin libc-l10n locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc-l10n locales
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5216 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libc6:amd64
```

I don't find any solution about this error.

Comment: While I was editing this question, I believe I have a lead for you.  Please add the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`   We need too verify this before continuing

Comment: I have the same error, mine prints `amd64`

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/11097#discussioncomment-8356353 / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77781232/apt-stucked-in-setting-up-libc6#comment137269112_77781232 worked for me